# Google TTS string issue on c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, text-to-speech, naudio

I am using google text to speech (TTS). Guys you all know it has only 100 character string support at a time. I have implemented TTS part correctly but not for greater than 100 characters. So as I said I'll get exception.

```
    public void Read(string text) // Lets say text has length 250 (>100)
    {
        DeleteFile();
        ReadText(text);
        PlaySound();
    }
```

I have a method to dispose audio:

```
    public void DisposeWave()
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Stop();
            output.Dispose();
            output = null;
        }
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            stream = null;
        }
    }
```

Also please consider i am using NAudio (using NAudio.Wave;).
How can I modify this code efficiently and play **entire string** audio without problem.

**Edited Question:**
When we use Google TTS you know there it will support 100 character string only at a single time. My problem is if my string is greater than 100 I will not allow to do TTS by google. So that I do want to split string into set of 100s and play the audio without conflict. How to do that?

Please help.

Comment: You have a lot of options, break the string `text` into chunks of less than 100, add a try catch, if statement that alerts the user it's longer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

change this method like

```
  public void Read(string text) // Lets say text has length 250 (>100)
    {
        DeleteFile();

        int startIndex = 0;
        string textToPlay = text;
        string remainingText = text;
        while (remainingText.Length > 100)
        {
            textToPlay = remainingText.Substring(startIndex, 100);

            startIndex = startIndex + 100;
            remainingText = text.Substring(startIndex);
            ReadText(textToPlay);
        }
        ReadText(remainingText);
        PlaySound();
    }
```

Comment: Yes this will split the string and ignore rest but I do want to play entire string :(

Comment: will playing in parts do it for you?

Comment: Yes I want to play entire string even it has 1000 of length.

Comment: Now this will play only rest. Any logic conflict here?

Comment: Hope there might require recursive method call?

Comment: yeah slight mistake. fixed.

Comment: can't be, i tested it this time before updating. show me your code

Comment: One problem with this is that it will likely slice words apart, resulting in TTS glitches.  You need to split the text at word boundaries at least, preferably entire sentences which are then split at a mid-sentence point if they are too long.